# What type of word is "certain"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What type of word is "certain"? As in the sentence:

"John wants to own a **certain** piano which used to belong to a famous pianist."

I have looked for some information. It tends to be classified as an adjective.

However, it seems to me that it is more an indefinite quantifier, but I am not sure.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Since there's no comma after piano, the relative clause is restrictive.  Apparently the famous musician owned several pianos, and John is interested only in a particular one.

Comment: Latin *quidam* (=a certain) is both indefinite pronoun and adjective.

Comment: I'd say adjective. It's a synonym for "particular, individual, special" etc., which are adjectives.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Alas, reviewing rules for commas won't help very much.  Review the rules for restrictive and non-restrictive clauses.

Answer (score 1):

*Certain* here is a [determiner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_determiners).  It supplies a reference to its associated noun without providing a description or modification.